# Runtime heap size set in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            long heapsize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
            System.out.println("heapsize is :: " + heapsize/(1024*1024));
        }

}
```

The output is:

heapsize is :: 245

Does this mean my runtime has only 245M memory? My computer has 8GB memory. I doubt output this is correct, since the running of Eclipse alone will consume a lot more than 245M.

In Eclipse, I click Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs, and set Default JVM arguments as follows:

```
-ea -Xms256m -Xmx4096M
```

Then run the test again. It still prints out the same number, 245. How could this happen?

Edited: from Java doc for Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory():

```
Returns the total amount of memory in the Java virtual machine. 
The value returned by this method may vary over time, depending on the 
host environment.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program doesn't run in Eclipse's heap space. Eclipse spawns off a separate JVM for your program.

`Runtime.totalMemory()` does indeed return the current heap size.

The `-Xms` argument specifies the *initial* heap size. Java will expand if it cannot free up enough memory through garbage collection until it reaches the maximum, as set by `-Xmx`. At this point, the JVM will exit with an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Java memory management is a complex topic, involving garbage collection, moving objects from nursery to tenured space, etc.

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory(), What does this show? I have a program which runs fine, but today suddenly I got this outofmemory message.

Comment: In Eclipse, "Windows->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs->Default JVM arguments" sets heap size for applications running in Eclipse, not for Eclipse itself.

Comment: Expanded my answer, hopefully addressing your follow-up questions

Comment: My Eclipse is running currently, so the runtime consumed should be much more than 245MB. I still don't understand why it only prints out 245MB. In my Linux performance monitor, I noticed that the memory usage is 3.6G.

Comment: As I state in my answer, your program runs in a separate JVM from Eclipse, so `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` will **not** return *any* info about Eclipse. Only your program's JVM.